# New ssd and new user

Tags: partitioning, ssd, users, disk

I'm a beginner with Linux and I just bought a new SSD with 1TB and physically installed it on my laptop, in which I`m running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
Aiming to separate work and play environments I created a new user.
So now I have

`christian` - working

`chris0reck` - playing games

But for some reason, when I try to run the command `df -h` in the terminal I get the following output

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3,1G  2,5M  3,1G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  468G  232G  213G  53% /
tmpfs            16G  371M   15G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1  511M  6,1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           3,1G  7,5M  3,1G   1% /run/user/1001
```

It's like the SSD isn't being recognized. But I know the system knows it is there because when I open Disks, I can see the following:

[image: figure].

Does anybody know if/how can I make use of this SSD from both user spaces?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**:
As instructed, I should create the partition and mount it, it seems. So I followed the steps found in this website: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive .

Here are the steps:

**First**: show partitions
$ sudo lshw -C disk

**Second**: partition with GParted, with 1MiB the left, ext4, primary partition, add and apply

**Third**: try to reserve 1% space for the super-user
$ sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda1

Fourth: Create mount point
$ sudo mkdir /media/myNewIntensoDrive

Fifth: add lines to `fstab` file
$ sudo gedit /etc/fstab

```
# new SSD Intenso automatic mounting at Boot
# on address /dev/sda1
UUID=cb6c6393-45fb-4e18-9f93-51455f259a37    /media/myNewIntensoDrive   ext4    defaults     0        2
```

Sixth: allow a normal user to create files on this drive

```
$ sudo chgrp plugdev /media/myNewIntensoDrive
$ sudo chmod g+w /media/myNewIntensoDrive
$ sudo chmod +t /media/myNewIntensoDrive
$ sudo chown -R chris0reck:chris0reck /media/myNewIntensoDrive
```

But I think I still can't write the SSD storage, because when I try to add the `/media/myNewIntensoDrive` as file storage option to Steam app, it doesn't work and I could drag files and release in the mounted SSD.
Here is how my disks look now: [image]

When inside what I believe is the mounting point I see the following:

```
chris0reck@chris-nitro:/media$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-x---+ 2 root       root       4096 set 28 20:51 christian
drwxrwxr-t  3 chris0reck chris0reck 4096 dez 21 21:40 myNewIntensoDrive
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Please edit your question to show a `ls -l` output on the mountpoint.

Comment: @OrganicMarble done it!

Comment: My samba shares are all mounted drwxrwxrwx Don't know if that is a smart way, but they work. You've shown a file inside the mountpoint, I believe. I was asking for the ls -l on the mountpoint itself (a level higher)

Comment: Sorry about that @OrganicMarble , just fixed. (Please let me know in case I misunderstood again).
It is safe to to mount like you said `drwxrwxrwx`? Will it be available in both users? And how could I do that? Sorry for so many questions, I'm new to this

Comment: The second disks screenshot is identical to the first. Is that a posting error or have you actually not created and formatted a partition?

Comment: Instructions are a bit old. You should not be using MBR(msdos) partitioning with newer systems. Microsoft has required UEFI with gpt partitioning since 2012. I have used gpt since 2010. The only time for MBR now is old system where you have to install Windows in BIOS mode. But conversion from MBR to gpt totally erases drive, so have good backups. With gparted select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting. Or `sudo parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt`
You can create a GPT partition table with g with fdisk See `man fdisk`

Answer (score -1):

@Christian Peck, thank you for bringing your problem to us! `df -h` only shows partitions that are mounted. Thus, if you're not seeing it here, then it isn't mounted. So here's how to fix the issue.

Step one, open disks and select the 1TB SSD that you've added. There *should* be a "Volume" or partition listed there. If there isn't, you will need to create one. Select the volume and click the gear icon just under it and to the left. Select "Mount Options". Now check "Mount at Start Up" and "Show in User Interface". Reboot and run `df -h` again and hopefully see your new volume.

Let me know if this solves your issue or if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Geary!
Okay, so I searched for a few websites and found this one https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive . I tried to follow all of the steps. 
However I have the impression I still can't write to the SSD (and when I try to add the drive as a possible storage address and the Steam app it doesn't work). I'm gonna write my steps in the next comment

Comment: Here's what I did (all on the main user which is `christian`):
First: show partitions
`$ sudo lshw -C disk`;
Second: partition with GParted, with 1MiB the left, ext4, primary partition, add and apply;
Third: try to reserve 1% space for super-user
`$ sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda1`;
Fourth: create mount point
`$ sudo mkdir /media/myNewIntensoDrive`;
Fifth: add lines to fstab file `$ sudo gedit /etc/fstab`:
"# new SSD Intenso automatic mounting at Boot
# on address /dev/sda1
UUID=cb6c6393-45fb-4e18-9f93-51455f259a37    /media/myNewIntensoDrive   ext4    defaults     0        2"

Comment: Finally
Sixth: allow a normal user to create files on this drive

`$ sudo chgrp plugdev /media/myNewIntensoDrive`

`$ sudo chmod g+w /media/myNewIntensoDrive`

`$ sudo chmod +t /media/myNewIntensoDrive`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write, in the last step I also executed the following command:

`$ sudo chown -R chris0reck:chris0reck /media/myNewIntensoDrive`